# Using preg_match to validate a nickname without spaces and letter variations

Tags: php, preg-match

I'm having problems with the way I validate nicknames:

```
preg_match("^[A-Za-z0-9]+$^", $nickname );
```

It works right but have one problem with it, which I can't fix, is that it allows white spaces and letter variations such as *é*, *ç*, *ñ* and I don't want to allow those. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that you should use `/^[A-Za-z0-9]+$/`. The `^` means beginning of the line, and `$` means end of the line. By wrapping your string in `^` you are making that the regex delimiter rather than the typical `/`. In this case `^` looses it's meaning of beginning of the line.

**Edit:** Better still is `/\A[A-Za-z0-9]+\z/`. This is a subtle modification. `^` could be the beginning of a line or the beginning of the string but `\A` is always the beginning of the string. Likewise `$` could be the end of a line or the end of the string but `\z` is the end of the string. So by using `^` and `$`, nicknames could contain linebreaks, but if you use `\A` and `\z` they can't.

Comment: A subtle modification to this is that `^` is the beginning of a line and `\A` is the beginning of the string. Likewise `$` is the end of a line and `\z` is the end of the string. So by using `^` and `$`, nicknames could contain linebreaks, but if you use `\A` and `\z` they can't.

Comment: See the [regex test](https://regex101.com/r/6q26BG/1). @jmarkmurphy - should the contents of you comment be moved into the body of the answer?

Comment: Note that in place of `\A` and `\z`, you can also use `^` and `$` with the D modifier: `/^[A-Za-z0-9]+$/D`

Comment: By default `^` matches the *start of the string* and `$` the *end of the string* or the position before the last character of the string if this one is a newline character. `^` and `$` match the start and end of line only with the multiline modifier.